# Should Outlook 2016 show mail icons for message classes "unread message" and "read/not replied message"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, icons, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have just migrated from Outlook 2010 to Outlook 2016. In Outlook 2010 I had icons (mostly envelope icons) for all different message classes/types, such as [image: unread message icon] unread message, [image: read message icon] read (but not replied/forwarded) message, [image: replied message icon] replied message, [image: forwarded icon] forwarded message, [image: ooo icon] auto-reply message, etc.

In Outlook 2016, I still have icons for some message classes/types, like replied, forwarded and OOO. But I no longer have icons for "unread" messages and "read (but not replied/forwarded)" messages. Is this just a "feature" of Outlook 2016 that these types of item no longer have icons, or is there a way to bring them back?

Answer (score 0):

1) Right click on the column heads and select **Field Chooser** from the context menu.

2) Use the drop-down at the top of the Field Chooser to filter by **All Mail Fields**.

3) Drag the **Read** field to place it among the existing column heads.

This will give you a dedicated icon column showing read/unread so it does not entirely replicate the status icon column from previous releases.

[image]